# Which is the true size?

Tags: modeling

Why is it that when I create an object with numbers in transforms, everything is 2m?
I want to model based on real world dimensions and this confuses me.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've scaled your object in *Object* mode, select them in *Object* mode and apply their scale (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Apply Scale*) and you'll see their real dimensions.